# AWS S3 rewrite url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This is an example bucket that represent my situation. The bucket is a static website, no problem for that.

> domain
>    --> index.html
>    --> folder1
>       --> index.html

In the aws documentation i read that if i call from a browser ***domain/folder1*** i receive an error but if i call ***domain/folder1/*** i will be redirect automatically to ***domain/folder1/index.html***

But in my case i receve always an error 403. Only if i manually go to ***domain/folder1/index.html*** i will see the page correctly.

Can someone explain me the cause? And help me to fix this problem.

Comment: Does it work for any other sub-folder? AWS mentions this "index.html" is case-sensitive, can you validate the index.html config?

Comment: It does't work in every situation. if i call domain/folder1/ it doesn't show me the correct page (and yes, index.html is in lower case)